# Does solid sodium hydroxide react with carbon dioxide and air moisture?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ionic-compounds

I heard a claim in the context of soapmaking that a stray grain of sodium hydroxide will decay into soda ash, i.e. sodium carbonate, on contact with air. This reaction happens in [an aqueous solution](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64570/would-sodium-carbonate-from-carbon-dioxide-plus-hydroxide-be-formed-in-solution), but I'm wondering how fast it would happen with only the air moisture absorbed by the hydroxide grain.

More to the point, some of the sodium hydroxide grains I have for soapmaking seems to have  stuck together into a solid lump by absorbing air moisture inside the closed container. Should I assume a nontrivial fraction of that has turned into sodium carbonate by now?

Comment: Rather reacts with aerial CO2, as compounds not containing carbon cannot decompose to compounds containing it.

Comment: a) nobody can guess how tight your closed containers are. b) what does carbonate do when you add a few drops of vinegar?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27221/why-do-carbon-dioxide-and-sodium-hydroxide-not-form-sodium-oxide-and-carbonic-ac

Comment: Consider that, even with vastly increased CO2 in the atmosphere since the Industrial Revolution, it's << one part in a thousand. Depending on the rate of infiltration into the container, the biggest contaminant is just water, fusing the pellets together -- NaOH is *very* hygroscopic.